# React Custom Component Styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

so I created a custom component for a constantly used Router Link, here is how it's JS File looks:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import styles from "./LNLink.module.css";

class LNLink extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Link className={styles.LNLink} to={this.props.to}>
        {this.props.text}
      </Link>
    );
  }
}

export default LNLink;
```

Now, this Component is called in my Login.js for example, as so:

```
            <LNLink
              to="/sign-up"
              text="Sign up"
              className={styles.loginSignUpLink}
            />
```

Now this all works fine functionally, the problem is that the classes assigned in Login.js, `className={styles.loginSignUpLink}`, are not being assigned, not assigned and overwritten, they are not in the browser inspection at all, why is that the case?

Bonus question: Instead of passing a `text` prop, would it be possible to instead send it in between `<LNLink>`and it's closing tag and have it be used in the same fashion?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

To answer the bonus part of your question you can pass whatever you want in between `<LNLink>` and then render it inside this component using `this.props.children`

`<LNLink>Whatever you want here (text, JSX, other components)</LNLink>`

```
return (
      <Link className={styles.LNLink} to={this.props.to}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Link>
);
```

Comment: It was that I wasn't using this.props.className that was being passed, check my answer and @albertarvesu 's.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should also use `className` as prop for LNLink. And `children` to get whatever is inside the tag.

```
class LNLink extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Link className={this.props.className} to={this.props.to}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Link>
    );
  }
}

export default LNLink;

<LNLink
  to="/sign-up"
  className={styles.loginSignUpLink}
/>
  Sign up
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out, the problem was that I'm not using the styling passed to the component, the fix is simple, just add `this.props.className` as a style on the component, so in my `LNLink.js` I amended the `className` to look as follows:

`className={classNames(styles.LNLink, this.props.className)}`

Now I'm using the `classNames` package cause it looks cleaner since I'm using css modules but if you're not you can type it as follows:

```
className={`${styles.LNLink} ${props.className`}
```